# Adding users to a Telegram Group

Tags: python, excel, api, telegram

I am writing a bot that takes numbers from the excel file and adds them to the Telegram group.

```
import telebot
import openpyxl

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

# Reading data from an Excel file
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Заречный.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active

contacts = []
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
    phone_number = row[0]
    name = row[1]
    city = row[2]
    operator = row[3]
    region = row[4]
    contacts.append((phone_number, name, city, operator, region))

# Adding contacts to the group
chat_id = '-1001658022999'
user_ids = []
for contact in contacts:
    phone_number = contact[0]
    name = contact[1]
    phone_number_digits_only = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, str(phone_number)))
    try:
        user = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, phone_number_digits_only)
        if user.status in ['member', 'administrator']:
            user_id = user.user.id
            user_ids.append(user_id)
    except telebot.apihelper.ApiException as e:
        print(f"Error adding member with phone number {phone_number_digits_only}: {e}")

if user_ids:
    bot.add_chat_members(chat_id, user_ids)
```

Outputs an error to the console:
Error adding member with phone number 89270932254: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: user not found

The numbers in the excel file are written in this format: 89270932254
This is a Russian number, and the code there is +7.
I read that in the telegram the first digit '7' is inserted by itself. That is, it should work in this format "9270932254".

I think the problem is in the format of the phone number and don't know how to enter it correctly.
Most likely the error means in this piece of code:

```
 phone_number_digits_only = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, str(phone_number)))
    try:
        user = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, phone_number_digits_only)
```

I will be glad of any help)